# Getting RuntimeException on JBoss AS 7

Tags: java, deployment, jboss, seam, jboss7.x

I am migrating a project using Seam 2.1.2  and JBoss 4.2.2 to JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final, but I'm getting a RuntimeException.

Before that, it loaded database SchemaUpdate.  It getting when loading seam conversaction classes.

```
: customerGroupController, scope: EVENT, type: JAVA_BEAN, class: com.manam.mobee    .customer.groups.CustomerGroupController
16:21:48,004 INFO  [org.jboss.seam.Component] (MSC service thread 1-1) Component    : customerStartUpLoader, scope: APPLICATION, type: JAVA_BEAN, class: com.manam.m    obee.customer.CustomerStartUpLoader
16:21:48,015 INFO  [org.jboss.seam.Component] (MSC service thread 1-1) Component    : dbList, scope: CONVERSATION, type: JAVA_BEAN, class: com.manam.mobee.settings.db.DatabaseMonitorController
16:21:48,026 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-    host].[/mobeeadmin]] (MSC service thread 1-1) Exception sending context initiali    zed event to listener instance of class com.manam.mobee.fwk.listener.MobeeSeamListener: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create Component: dbendPointHome
        at org.jboss.seam.init.Initialization.addComponent(Initialization.java:1202) [jboss-seam.jar:2.1.2]
        at org.jboss.seam.init.Initialization.installComponents(Initialization.java:1118) [jboss-seam.jar:2.1.2]
        at org.jboss.seam.init.Initialization.init(Initialization.java:733) [jboss-seam.jar:2.1.2]
        at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamListener.contextInitialized(SeamListener.java:36) [jboss-seam.jar:2.1.2]
        at com.manam.mobee.fwk.listener.MobeeSeamListener.contextInitialized(MobeeSeamListener.java:36) [classes:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_27]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_27]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_27]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jmx/snmp/daemon/CommunicationException
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_27]
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427) [rt.jar:1.6.0_27]
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2547) [rt.jar:1.6.0_27]
        at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1410) [rt.jar:1.6.0_27]
        at org.jboss.seam.Component.hasAnnotation(Component.java:1158) [jboss-seam.jar:2.1.2]
        at org.jboss.seam.Component.<init>(Component.java:218) [jboss-seam.jar:2.1.2]
        at org.jboss.seam.Component.<init>(Component.java:205) [jboss-seam.jar:2.1.2]
        at org.jboss.seam.init.Initialization.addComponent(Initialization.java:1186) [jboss-seam.jar:2.1.2]
        ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jmx.snmp.daemon.CommunicationException from [Module deployment.mobeeadmin.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
        ... 20 more

16:21:48,723 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-1) Initializing Mojarra 2.1.7-jbossorg-1 (20120227-1401) for context '/mobeeadmin'
16:21:50,772 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-1) Error listenerStart
16:21:50,776 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-1) Context [/mobeeadmin] startup failed due to previous errors
16:21:50,790 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./mobeeadmin: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./mobeeadmin: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:95)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_27]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_27]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_27]

16:21:51,483 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
16:21:51,487 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015875: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started (with errors) in 51988ms - Started 492 of 572 services (2 services failed or missing dependencies, 77 services are passive or on-demand)
16:21:51,686 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "mobeeadmin.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.web.deployment.default-host./mobeeadmin" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./mobeeadmin: JBAS018040: Failed to start context"}}
16:21:51,739 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS011403: Stopping Persistence Unit Service 'mobeeadmin.war#mobeeadmin'
16:21:54,377 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment mobeeadmin.war in 2688ms
16:21:54,382 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./mobeeadmin: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.
web.deployment.default-host./mobeeadmin: JBAS018040: Failed to start context

16:21:54,397 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.web.deployment.default-host./mobeeadmin" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./mobeeadmin: JBAS018040: Failed to start context"}}}}
```

Here is my jboss-deployment-structure.xml:

```xml
<jboss-deployment-structure>
  <ear-subdeployments-isolated>false</ear-subdeployments-isolated>
  <deployment>
     <dependencies>
          <module name="javax.faces.api" slot="1.2" export="true"/>
          <module name="com.sun.jsf-impl" slot="1.2" export="true"/>
          <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" export="true"/>
          <module name="org.dom4j" export="true"/>
          <module name="org.apache.commons.collections" export="true"/>
     </dependencies>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```